How to retrieve a partition accidently turned into green "Free space"?
I accidently ran some commands -couldn't specify which, but I assume I did something using 'mountvol' that was recommended online-. After that I found partition 'D' turned into "Free space" (green) and framed into "Extended partition" (dark green frame) and another partition -that was dedicated to EFI files for a Linux system- gained the letter 'D'.
Is there a way to undo this and return the partition to its normal state without the need to use data recovery tools? (I tried partition recovery tool and could not do it).

(Update:
I ran the DMDE tool as suggested, and it shows the partition as an unallocated space within an extended partition. However, it shows a partition in place with 215GB that actually was present some time ago along with some ~500GB partition and I merged them into one ~750GB partition):

After running 'Full Scan', it shows these two old partitions:

Will retrieving these two partitions preserve the data that was in the 750GB partition in its last state?

It is possible - at the very least, the data on that partition almost certainly is still there. However, it is unlikely that any tech support forum could coach you through doing so, particularly since you don't even remember what you did. Restoring the partition would probably require specialized tools and direct access to the drive.

In somewhat similar issue in this article: https://superuser.com/questions/271061/accidentally-changed-partition-type-while-trying-to-get-a-ext-luks-encrypted-lin someone suggested changing the type of the partition from 'extended' to its original type. Would that help?

Without knowing what you did it is impossible to guarantee a solution.  Thus the first step you should do is a full bitcopy of your entire drive - in case you stuff up the recovery.    Under Linux, ddrescue is a good tool to use for this.  I don't use Windows, but I suspect you might be able to use something like Easeus Disk Copy.  Ensure you copy the whole disk, and not a partition copy.
Once you have a backup, try using testdisk (a free Linux tool which is part of the photorec suite).  This tool can scan your disk and look for deleted partitions based on signatures, and has an excellent chance of restoring your partition.

The green partition is an extended partition with no partition in it. In the past, this would've been seen as unused space, and there is no data in it. If there used to be, then whatever command you ran in Linux removed its data, and you need data recovery without doing anything to the partitions.
If you just want to use the free space, you can remove the extended partition, and create a new primary partition in its place.
